# Finding a list item using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

I have a list of files, each item in the list is the name of the file followed by various information like creation date. I need a way to check if the list contains a file using just the file name.

So if a list contains:

```
[fileName1#date#otherinfo, fileName2#date#otherinfo]
```

Is there a regex to find whether the list contains fileName1(+any number of characters) if I don't know what the date or other info is?

Comment: Why not iterate through the list, for each file, get the name and use `contains()`?

Comment: What kind of list do you use? A list of strings or a list of some other objects?

Comment: It is a list of Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `List<T>#contains()`expects a `<T>` parameter.

What you can do is iterate over the list and check for a match.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("fileName124567268xtz");
list.add("1234);
String regex = "fileName.*";
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
 if(list.get(i).matches(regex))
  System.out.println(list.get(i));
```